# Correct phrase for "ignoring pending operations" in a document stating the balance of a bank account?

Tags: phrase-request

I am writing a certificate stating the balance of a bank account:

> The balance of bank account X is 10,000 USD, *ignoring pending operations*

By "ignoring pending operations", I mean that there might be some ongoing transfers that would make the balance differs from 10,000 USD.

What would be a more correct phrase for "ignoring pending operations"?

E.g., in French, the [proper phrase typically used by a bank would be](https://www.ca-lorraine.fr/cgu.html) *sous réserve des opérations en cours de traitement*.

Comment: I would expect to see *pending transactions* (AmE).

Comment: @user3169 Thanks! *"ignoring potential pending transactions*"?

Comment: I am not sure if you need *potential*. Do you have a particular reasoning? If there is a future pending transaction, do you also want to exclude its resolution relating to the balance?

Comment: @user3169 Just to make sure that the reader understands that there aren't necessarily pending transactions.

Comment: Then maybe "ignoring *possible* pending transactions"?

Comment: @user3169 I see what you mean, good point, *possible* might indeed be a better choice.

Comment: I would expect *excluding* rather than *ignoring*.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, I also feel it's a better option.

Comment: Rather surprisingly (perhaps something's gone wrong with my browser! :), Google claims to have no results at all for ["excluding pending operations"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zjVrV56qD-_S8Aeugr2YAw#q=%22excluding+pending+operations%22) or ["not including pending operations"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=7jVrV53ABeLS8Ael_K6YAQ#q=%22not+including+pending+operations%22). And the only hits for ["ignoring pending operations"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=bzdrV4XLO-vS8Afk1Z6YBQ#q=%22ignoring+pending+operations%22) are this very ELL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A balance statement will usually have a cutoff time after which transactions will not be included in the reported balance.

These can be described as

> Certain transactions may not be reflected in the balance shown.
>   Transactions after 12:30PM are not included in the balance shown.
>   You may have pending transactions which are not shown in the balance provided.

all these have the meaning

> excluding pending transactions